# Is there a standard XML format to add metadata to a generic dataset?

Tags: sql, xml, standards

I need to save a generic dataset generated from SQL query result as XML. I'd like do add metadata to my resultset in order to make it reversible so anyone can create a DB table starting from the XML and load the data.
I was wondering if there is a standard XML format that can address this issue.

Comment: Very important: Which RDBMS (product and version)? What metadata? Please provide (reduced) sample data and expected output. Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes.  The Root tag is the DataSet name.  Next level tags is the DataTable names.  Next Level is the column names for the parent DataTable followed by the row data.  Best way is to create a test DataSet and then use the ds.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: Of course I forgot to mention I'm on Oracle 11gR2. You gave me a good hint... I've never heard about any built-in command able to describe the cursor as XML in Oracle, haven't you? Anyway, I can code it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your RDBMS. For SQL Server you might use [`FOR XML RAW` together with `XMLDATA` or `XMLSCHEMA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510461.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeText VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, SomeInt INT);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES('row 1',1),('row 2',2);
```

### Example `XMLDATA`

```
SELECT * FROM @Dummy FOR XML RAW,XMLDATA

<Schema name="Schema2" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <ElementType name="row" content="empty" model="closed">
    <AttributeType name="ID" dt:type="i4" />
    <AttributeType name="SomeText" dt:type="string" />
    <AttributeType name="SomeInt" dt:type="i4" />
    <attribute type="ID" />
    <attribute type="SomeText" />
    <attribute type="SomeInt" />
  </ElementType>
</Schema>
<row xmlns="x-schema:#Schema2" ID="1" SomeText="row 1" SomeInt="1" />
<row xmlns="x-schema:#Schema2" ID="2" SomeText="row 2" SomeInt="2" />
```

### Example XMLSCHEMA (more details)

```
SELECT * FROM @Dummy FOR XML RAW,XMLSCHEMA

<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="row">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="sqltypes:int" use="required" />
      <xsd:attribute name="SomeText" use="required">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
            <xsd:maxLength value="100" />
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:attribute>
      <xsd:attribute name="SomeInt" type="sqltypes:int" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet2" ID="1" SomeText="row 1" SomeInt="1" />
<row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet2" ID="2" SomeText="row 2" SomeInt="2" />
```

### Standard-Schema .Net

Following jdweng's comment this is an approach with C#:

```
var ds = new System.Data.DataSet("SomeName");
ds.Tables.Add("SomeTable");
ds.Tables.Add("OneMoreTable");
var t1 = ds.Tables["SomeTable"];
t1.Columns.Add("SomeInt", typeof(int));
t1.Columns.Add("SomeString", typeof(string));
var t2 = ds.Tables["OneMoreTable"];
t2.Columns.Add("SomeInt", typeof(int));
t2.Columns.Add("SomeDate", typeof(DateTime));

t1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "test 1" });
t1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "test 2" });
t1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "test 3" });

t2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DateTime.Now });

ds.WriteXml(@"c:\SomePath\test.dataset", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

This is the written content (embedded schema and data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<SomeName>
  <xs:schema id="SomeName" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="SomeName" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="SomeTable">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SomeInt" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SomeString" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="OneMoreTable">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SomeInt" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SomeDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <SomeTable>
    <SomeInt>1</SomeInt>
    <SomeString>test 1</SomeString>
  </SomeTable>
  <SomeTable>
    <SomeInt>2</SomeInt>
    <SomeString>test 2</SomeString>
  </SomeTable>
  <SomeTable>
    <SomeInt>3</SomeInt>
    <SomeString>test 3</SomeString>
  </SomeTable>
  <OneMoreTable>
    <SomeInt>1</SomeInt>
    <SomeDate>2017-02-02T10:23:39.2277162+01:00</SomeDate>
  </OneMoreTable>
</SomeName>
```